# how to implement blackberry application that will work on both mode (portrait and landscape)

Tags: landscape, blackberry-storm, landscape-portrait, fieldmanager

i m working with one blackberry application os 5.0 and letter , that is working fine in `portrait` Mode . when i swich device to `landscape` Mode , layout of that perticular screen switch into `portrait` to `landscape` and that time right side of the screen display White color .

so how to handle the application in `landscape` mode with Design and all `Manager` ?

how to get device current mode (landscape and portrait )?

please guide me its argent ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Display.getOrientation()` to get the current device orientation.  If you do custom drawing, you may also need to use `Display.getDirection()` to determine which edge of the display is "on top". Use `UiEngineInstance.setAcceptableDirections()` to specify which orientations/directions you want to support. If the orientation changes, your Screen's `sublayout()` method gets called again, which gives you oppurtunity to reposition your controls appropriately for the new orientation.